# New Document Validation: CouchDB

Tags: javascript, validation, couchdb, document

Could someone give me a pointer as to why this works as a new document  validation function:

```
{ 
  "_id": "_design/must_have_field_verifier", 
  "_rev": "14-7aa573a99ec8cb007edfe6c8dd72ba15", 
  "validate_doc_update": "function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) { 
 function require(field, message) { 
 message = message || \"Document must have a \" + field; 
  if (!newDoc[field]) throw({forbidden : message}); 
}; 
{ 
 require(\"abc\"); 
 } 
}" 
}
```

but `'abc.def'` is not 'recognised' in the code below, although the code is 
valid:

```
{ 
  "_id": "_design/must_have_field_verifier", 
  "_rev": "14-7aa573a99ec8cb007edfe6c8dd72ba15", 
  "validate_doc_update": "function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) { 
 function require(field, message) { 
 message = message || \"Document must have a \" + field; 
  if (!newDoc[field]) throw({forbidden : message}); 
}; 
{ 
 require(\"abc.def\"); 
 } 
}" 
}
```

The reply is:

> "Save failed: Document must have a abc.def"

My new document qualifies as a valid entry and contains "abc.def":"some text".

I have tried including : `typeof  (!newDoc[field]) === 'object'` 
inside an if statement but cannot get the javascript set out correctly

I am sure the answer is a simple one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this question [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-expenses-couchdb-angular/).(In the 
Adding Validation section about 2/3rds of the way down the article.(By Robert Kowalski  August 28, 2014.))

The adapted code is:(hope I have corrected it correctly)

```
{
"_id": "_design/verifier",
"_rev": "5-33f3ff3d650bf1594a9357af58153232",
"validate_doc_update": "function (newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) {\n  if     (newDoc.type == \"xyz\"){\n    if (newDoc._deleted === true) {\n      return;\n    }\n    if (!newDoc.abc) {\n      throw({forbidden: \"Document must have an abc.\"});\n    }\n    if (!newDoc.def) {\n      throw({forbidden: \"Document must have a def.\"});\n    }\n  if (!newDoc.ghi) {\n      throw({forbidden: \"Document must have a ghi.\"});\n    }\n  if (!newDoc.jkl.mno) {\n      throw({forbidden: \"Document must have a jkl mno.\"});\n }\n  if (!newDoc.pqr.stu) {\n      throw({forbidden: \"Document must have a pqr stu.\"});\n }\n if (!newDoc.vwx.yyy) {\n      throw({forbidden: \"Document must have a vwx yyy.\"});\n   }\n   }\n  }"
}
```